# How to navigate back to the correct one screen before the previous in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, onbackpressed

I have four compose screens and by clicking on their items user leads to my AdShowScreen then after watching the ad they lead to the FinalShow screen. like the image below
[image]

Now I want to navigate correctly back from finalShowScreen to one of the four compose screens that came from by overriding the back press button in FinalShowScreen.
This is my navGraph.

```
@SuppressLint("UnrememberedMutableState")
@Composable
fun MyNavGraph(

navController: NavHostController) {
val actions = remember(navController) { MainActions(navController) }

NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = BottomNavItems.First.route
 ) {
    composable(BottomNavItems.First.route) {
        FirstScreen(actions)
    }
    composable(BottomNavItems.Second.route) {
        SecondScreen(navController, actions)
    }
    composable(BottomNavItems.Third.route) {
        ThirdScreen()
    }
    composable(Screens.Fourth.route) {
        FourthScreen(navController, actions)
    }
         
    composable("${Screens.FinalShow.route}/{maskArg}") {
        val maskArg = it.arguments?.getString("maskArg")
        if (maskArg != null) {
            FinalShowScreen(
                maskArg = maskArg, navController,actions
            )
        }
    }
    
    
    composable("${Screens.RewardedShow.route}/{maskArg}") {
        val maskArg = it.arguments?.getString("maskArg")
        if (maskArg != null) {
            RewardedShowCompose(
                maskArg = maskArg, navController = navController, actions = actions
            )
        }
      }
   }
}

class MainActions(navController: NavController) {
val goToRoute: (String) -> Unit = { route ->
    navController.navigate(route) {
        navController.graph.startDestinationRoute?.let { rout ->
            popUpTo(rout) {
                saveState = true
            }
        }
        launchSingleTop = true
        restoreState = true
    }
  }
 
}
```

I'm trying this code below but It doesn't work. it goes back to AdShowScreen

```
 val gotoAdShow: (String, String) -> Unit = { maskArg, route ->
    navController.navigate("$route/$maskArg") {
        navController.graph.startDestinationRoute?.let { rout ->
            popUpTo(rout) {
                saveState = true
                inclusive = true
            }
        }
        launchSingleTop = true
        restoreState = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using

```
navController.navigate(route) {
    navController.graph.startDestinationRoute?.let { rout ->
        popUpTo(rout) {
            saveState = true
        }
    }
    launchSingleTop = true
    restoreState = true
}
```

What if instead you use `navHostController.popBackStack("ad", inclusive = true)` directly?

Comment: Thanks again, @David A. I know that this is the correct way but I cannot implement it, I don't know why it doesn't work. I used this method for my  BottomNavigation and it works well. Could you please see my code I added the code to my question. The last code.

Comment: I've updated my answer according to your code, please give it a try

Comment: It doesn't work. I think I should use currentBackStackEntryAsState(), but I don't know how.

Comment: Is your code open? Can I run it somehow?

Comment: No, it's not open.

Comment: Ok if you cannot figure it out by yourself, I suggest you make a basic sample app with the same navigation logic and post it to github, I'd be glad to have a look

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the link of the project  https://github.com/raghababa/MyProjeckt

Comment: Hi Razi, there are too many problems with the project. First you have to separate the navigation logic to be handled only by your MyNavGraph.kt,  
What I see is that some screens use the file but then you just do navigateUp in the TopBar()

Also you need to add navigation handling in RewardShowComposable and FinalShowScreen

After you separated all navigation calls you need to start test them one by one to see if each one does what you want, currently you just have 
`launchSingleTop = true, restoreState = true, launchSingleTop = true` everywhere.
Hope this helps

Comment: Ya thanks. I'm very new and should work on it.

Comment: No worries, you are already building stuff which is very good. If you haven't done so already I would suggest doing the labs in https://developer.android.com/courses/jetpack-compose/course pay attention to State Hoisting and Navigation labs

Answer (score 0):

To navigate back from the final screen to the first one, add this to the `FourthScreen` Composable;

```
BackHandler {
  navController.navigate(BottomNavItems.First.route) // Or to whichever route you want to navigate to
}
```

Also, it is not a good practice to pass the `navController` to other Composables because it will make your UI pretty hard to test.

Comment: Thanks @Richard Onslow Roper. The code doesn't work. regarding the navController you mean in all compose I create new         val navController = rememberNavController()

Comment: Use state-hoisting to pass the controller navigation logic down to the composables. Just take the Navigation Compose codelab. It has all the resources you'll need.